# change vim status line while executing command

Tags: unix, vim

I would like to change the vim status line which is shown while vim is busy executing an external command. 
I have a vim script which pipes lines of text from vim into some external program using "!". After execution vim waits for the output of the command to replace the lines with it. While it is waiting I would like to show the status of the external command in the statusline.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this using a temporary global variable. Here is a simple function that returns the value of a variable `g:temp_var` if it exists, otherwise it returns an empty string:

```
function! TemporaryStatus()
    if exists("g:temp_var")
        return g:temp_var
    else
        return ""
    endif
endfunction
```

You can set the statusline to use the return value of this function like this:

```
set statusline=%!TemporaryStatus()
```

Then, when you call the slow external command, just set the temporary variable beforehand (using the message you want to be displayed), and `unlet` it afterwards. For example:

```
...
let g:temp_var = "I am calling a slow external command"
redraw!
call SlowExternalCommand()
unlet g:temp_var
redraw!
...
```

Note that the `redraw!` commands are necessary to make sure Vim updates the display (and therefore uses the updated value of `g:temp_var` in the statusline).

**EDIT**

Of course it would be much simpler to display the message by echoing it and clearing the display afterwards, like this:

```
...
redraw!
echo "I am calling a slow external command"
call SlowExternalCommand()
redraw!
...
```

This way the message will be displayed on the Vim command line, rather than in the statusline. You don't need any of the functions defined above.

Comment: I see. But what I need is an updated status line. E.g. it should show the progress of the slow external command: 5% 10% 15% (note the progress information itself is produced by the external command and can be written to a pipe or file from which vim could read it). But the crucial issue is whether the status line allows for updates while it executes the external command.

Comment: You can't do this using `!`, I'm afraid. `!` suspends Vim during the system call. You could try using `!start` (see `:help :!start`) which claims not to suspend Vim - but I have never used it. If it works, you could then update `g:temp_var` while the command is running.

Comment: But this probably means that I cannot have the output of the command inserted in the file, can I?

Comment: I think it would be possible to temporarily insert a marker (some unique text snippet) where the commands output should be inserted and to replace this marker latter with the output. But how do I signal to vim when the command is finished so it know when to read the command output.